# How do I reset a KendoDropDownList selected index back to -1 (nothing selected)

Tags: kendo-ui

When a `KendoDropDownList` is created it's initial index is set to -1 and the text is empty.

IE: `$("#txtQPLPickupFrom").data("kendoDropDownList").select()` would return a -1.

When a selection is made, the `select()` returns the selected index (0,1,2,3...).

My question is, I want to return the selected index back to -1 when I am displaying an new record entry where the user has not selected a value. Trying to use `.select(-1)` does not seem to work. So it there a way to restore the initial selection to nothing (-1) after it's already had a value.

Comment: Do you have an example of this? The Kendo UI demos seem show an index of 0 for no selection unless no data is present.

Comment: In my application the items in the dropdownlist are dynamic, based on the record being displayed. So on initial creation the dataSource is set to an empty datasource, IE: new kendo.data.DataSource(). Then when I am displaying a record I load the datasource (via an AJAX call). This is why the initial selected index is -1.

Answer (score 6):

This should work:

```
$("#txtQPLPickupFrom").data("kendoDropDownList").value(-1);
```

Here is a fiddle (not mine): http://jsfiddle.net/EaNm4/124/

Comment: $("#txtQPLPickupFrom").data("kendoDropDownList").select(-1);

Answer (score 3):

The kendo dropdown will always default to the first item in its datasource. You could configure the dropdown to use `optionLabel: ' '` (a space), which will cause the initial value selected to have no text.

You could then reset the selection to this value with `.select(0)`.

Comment: No, what I really want is to reset the control back to it's initial state so that .select() will return -1 and the text will be blank.

Comment: I don't know how you could do that, except maybe setting the datasource to empty again. What are you trying to do that .select()=0 and ' ' is not enough?

Comment: Select(0), selects an entry (the 1st). When I am displaying a record where this value has never been selected, I want nothing selected. (and creating the 1st entry as a 'nothing is selected' entry is not what I want). Kind of the difference between 0 and null.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work: (I have to do more testing)

```
var txtQPLPickupFrom = $("#txtQPLPickupFrom").data("kendoDropDownList");
txtQPLPickupFrom.text(txtQPLPickupFrom.options.optionLabel);
txtQPLPickupFrom.element.val("");
txtQPLPickupFrom.selectedIndex = -1;
```

Comment: In order to get the change event to fire as well, I did find some more properties that looked interesting.  the _OldIndex seemed to be the one preventing any events from firing, so in order to get it fully working:

            var dropdownlist = $("#HolidayDropDownList").data("kendoDropDownList");
            dropdownlist.text(dropdownlist.options.optionLabel);
            dropdownlist.element.val(-1);
            dropdownlist.selectedIndex = -1;
            dropdownlist._oldIndex = 0;

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
$("#Actions").data("kendoDropDownList").refresh();
```

Answer (score 1):

use txtQPLPickupFrom.value(-1)

```
txtQPLPickupFrom.value(-1);
```

this should set it to empty